# QtWebkit: How to check HTTP status code?

Tags: qt, http-status-codes, qtwebkit

I'm writing a thumbnail generator as per [an example in the QtWebkit documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebpage.html#using-qwebpage-in-a-widget-less-environment). I would like to avoid screenshots of error pages such as `404 not found` or `503 Internal server error`.

However, the [QWebPage::loadFinished()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebpage.html#loadFinished) signal is always emitted with `ok = true` even when the page gives an HTTP error. Is there a way in QtWebkit to check the HTTP status code on a response?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out you need to monitor the [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) associated with your QWebPage and wait for a [finished(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) signal. You can then inspect the HTTP response and check its status code by asking for the `QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute` attribute.

It's better explained in code:

```
void MyClass::initWebPage()
{
  myQWebPage = new QWebPage(this);
  connect(
    myQWebPage->networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
    this, SLOT(httpResponseFinished(QNetworkReply *))
  );
}

void MyClass::httpResponseFinished(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
  switch (reply->error())
  {
    case QNetworkReply::NoError:
      // No error
      return;
    case QNetworkReply::ContentNotFoundError:
      // 404 Not found
      failedUrl = reply->request.url();
      httpStatus = reply->attribute(
        QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
      httpStatusMessage = reply->attribute(
        QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toByteArray();
      break;
    }
}
```

There are more [NetworkErrors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#NetworkError-enum) to choose from, e.g. for TCP errors or HTTP 401.

Comment: FWIW, one can also query the HTTP status code directly with  QNetworkReply::Attribute and QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute, see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkreply.html#attribute.

Comment: One thing you may not want is to trigger this function for each asset on a web page that fails to load; for example images and JavaScript. Ideally you probably only care if the main page itself doesn't load.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I'm using in a porting project. It checks the reply and decides to start backing off making request or not. The backing off part is in progress but I left the comments in.

```
QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
Q_CHECK_PTR(reply);

QVariant statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
if (!statusCode.isNull() && statusCode.toInt() >= 400){
    //INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE_BACKOFF;
    qDebug() << "server returned invalid response." << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString();
    return;
}else if (!statusCode.isNull() && statusCode.toInt() != 200){
    //INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE_NOBACKOFF;
    qDebug() << "server returned invalid response." << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString();
    return;
}
```