# How to get the error message from a failed url load in a Qt WebView

Tags: qt, signals, qml

say I have a basic QML file which listens for the onLoadFailed signal like this:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import QtWebKit 1.0

WebView
{
  onLoadFailed: {

  }

  url: "bogus_url"
}
```

In this example, I should get a 404 or a 500. **What should I put in the onLoadFailed to output the error message that was returned?**

Comment: I would definitely suggest you take a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330274/qtwebkit-how-to-check-http-status-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do it using a simple QML WebView.

You can use a [bad] trick described in this [thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3754) on the QT forum.

Otherwise you'll have to make your own QDeclarativeItem extending the WebView with all the infos you need.